# JSP - transferring data from controller to scriptlet

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to using JSP and i'm trying to do something like:

```
<% for (int i=0; i<numTables; i++) { %>
<h3> person <%=i%></h3>
<% } %>
```

numTables is a variable in the HomeController class.
I've also executed in the controller:

```
 model.addAttribute("numTables", numTables);
```

and if I write:

```
<h1>${numTables}</h1>
```

It prints the correct value. But I couldn't find a way to put this value as the
value of numTables in the for loop.
please help. thanks.

Edit: It has to be done with scriptlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored as a request attribute:

```
Integer numtables = (Integer) request.getAttribute("numTables");
```

Or whenever you're unsure in which scope it is:

```
Integer numtables = (Integer) pageContext.findAttribute("numTables");
```

However, you're going the wrong path by avoiding taglibs like [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). *Scriptlets* are [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) since JSP 2.0 which was released almost a decade(!) ago. If I were your CS tutor, you'd get negatives for this.

Comment: In which part of the specification in JSP 2.x does it say scriptlets are discouraged?

Comment: @RaulLapeiraHerrero: click the "discouraged" link in answer. For an related Q&A see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733

Comment: The fact that JSTL proposes not using java in JSPs does not mean the JSP 2.x discourages it... in the spec there is no mention to such a thing.

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment for relevant quotes which you apparently missed from the coding conventions document.

Comment: I missed nothing. I am informing you a convention document is not the specification discouraging anything, but thanks for pointing out a 10 year old specification is old.

Answer (score 3):

You are better off avoiding scriptlets.  JSTL tags can perform the same function e.g.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${numTables}" >
    <h3>person ${i}</h3>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i have to do it with scriptlets. is there a way?

Comment: If you absolutely must use scriptlets, check BalusCs answer.